# I am not able to receive the correct ID with from my Spring restApi

Tags: java, hibernate, curl

I have model customer

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_customer")
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="financeSeqGen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="financeSeqGen",sequenceName="finance_sequence")
  @Column(name="CustomerId")
  private long CustomerId;
  @Column(name="name")
  private String name;
  @Column(name="street")
  private String street;
  @Column(name="houseNumber")
  private String houseNumber;
  @Column(name="zipcode")
  private String zipcode;
  @Column(name="place")
  private String place;
  @Column(name="email")
  private String email;
  @Column(name="phonenumber")
  private String phonenumber;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
  private Set<Contract> contracts = new HashSet<>();

  public long getCustomerId() {
    return CustomerId;
  }

  public void setCustomerId(long customerId) {
    CustomerId = customerId;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getStreet() {
    return street;
  }

  public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
  }

  public String getHouseNumber() {
    return houseNumber;
  }

  public void setHouseNumber(String houseNumber) {
    this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
  }

  public String getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
  }

  public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
  }

  public String getPlace() {
    return place;
  }

  public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public String getPhonenumber() {
    return phonenumber;
  }

  public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
  }

  @XmlTransient
  @JsonIgnore
  public Set<Contract> getContracts() {
    return contracts;
  }

  public void setContracts(Set<Contract> contracts) {
    this.contracts = contracts;
  }


  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Customer[" +
        "CustomerId=" + CustomerId +
        ", name='" + name + '\'' +
        ", street='" + street + '\'' +
        ", houseNumber='" + houseNumber + '\'' +
        ", zipcode='" + zipcode + '\'' +
        ", place='" + place + '\'' +
        ", email='" + email + '\'' +
        ", phonenumber='" + phonenumber + '\'' +
        ']';
  }
}
```

And I try to update the exciting Customer with ID 1(The update part works):

```
  @PostMapping("/custer")
  public ResponseEntity<Customer> updateCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customerDetails){
    Customer c1 = customerDetails;
    //Customer customer = financeService.updateCustomer(c1);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(c1);
  }
```

This is the result of Debugging:
[image]

As you see the customerId is changing from 1 to zero (this also occurs if I change 1 to 2 or something else)

My Curl request is like:
`curl --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"CustomerId":1,"name":"Jen","street":"Spanker","houseNumber":"20","zipcode":"3077ZD","email":"nakzo","place":"Amsterveen", "phonenumber":"06234234"}' localhost:5050/finance/update/custer`

Why is the customerId with 1 changing to 0?

Comment: Have you tried logging the ID _before_ you call `updateCustomer()`? Because from that debugging screenshot, there's no way of telling when `customerDetails` was evaluated.

Comment: Yes I did, I added another picture and edited my code to show the problem better.

Comment: try to put Column annotation for CustomerId property too. It's only difference between other properties

Comment: @AntonTokmakov you mean adding `@Column(name="CustomerId")
  private long CustomerId;` that did not help unfortunately

Comment: I believe @RobbyCornelissen meant you should debug and check what is the payload before updating (not the result). Additionally, you can log the generated SQL with this: 
`logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG 
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE` 
can you update the question with this information? Also, maybe share what is happening in financeService - is it a straight-forward call to the repo?

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir the hibernate part is not relevant because the object `Customer c1 = customerDetails;` does not with the hibernate yet or am I wrong? because customerDetails is the object that i pass with my curl post

Comment: oh, so you have this problem only when deserializing this json (before reaching hibernate). what else is in the `Customer` class? do you have getters and setters? What constructors do you have? `0` will be the default value for a long primitive and default constructor with no args. maybe jackson is missing a setter for that field?

Comment: @jenniferruurs would you mind sharing the getters and setters of the `Customer` class? As I saw your curl body `{"CustomerId":1,"name":"Jen","street":"Spanker","houseNumber":"20","zipcode":"3077ZD","email":"nakzo","place":"Amsterveen", "phonenumber":"06234234"}`, when I change `CustomerId` to `customerId`, it can respond with your input value `1`.

Comment: can you try changing your body to `{"customerId":1,"name":"Jen","street":"Spanker","houseNumber":"20","zipcode":"3077ZD","email":"nakzo","place":"Amsterveen", "phonenumber":"06234234"}` and see if it changes the output?

Comment: @PhilKu changing the capital letter was the issue indeed!